# While adding ADO.NET entity data model the Visual Studio 2017 does not showing server name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I want to connect my database from SQL server 2014 to MVC project by using **ADO.NET entity data model**.

The following steps that I taken:

1. Right click on **Model** folder then click on **Add** then click on **New Item**
2. select **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** and renamed it and clicked on **Add** button
3. On Entity Data Model Wizard I selected **EF Designer from Database** and clicked on **Next** button
4. clicked on **New Connection** and choose Data source as **Microsoft SQL Server** and clicked on **next** button
5. on the option **Server name** the server list is shown with empty list

Comment: You can type the server name by yourself. The server you are looking for is connectable from SSMS?

Comment: What is SSMS mean?

Comment: SSMS = Sql Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Object Explorer, right-click a server, and then click Properties
2. Copy Server name that is present in first row in front of the **Name**
3. e.g: DESKTOP-D1AHL5B\SQL2014
4. Past this name in the server list and click on Test connection

i hope this will help